# What formulae should I use to enable one body in motion to catch up with the other and vice versa?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hope someone can help! I'm looking to determine 2 similar mathematical formulae that will describe the required acceleration and deceleration I'm looking for. This will ultimately be implemented as C/C++ code, so would most welcome suggestions as code snippets but will take all the help I can get!

The scenario is that there are two cars traveling at exactly the same speed (100% of ideal speed), but one ahead of the other in two side-by-side lanes along a straight road. I would like to be able to mathematically define the two curves that would result in the two cars traveling next to each other at the same speed (100% of ideal speed), either as a result of the car behind catching up to the one ahead, or as a result of the car ahead slowing down to match the car behind. In either case, they need to end up traveling at the same speed (100% of ideal speed) and next to each other.

I need these curves to be described using sine or cosine (or very similar) so that the changes in speed are exponential (to smooth out the acceleration/deceleration). It's important that there is a gradual change from the initial speed as the acceleration or deceleration takes hold. I have included example curves as pictures to demonstrate what I'm looking for.

There are two input variables that need to be factored:

**Variable 1** - The positional difference between the two cars known in milliseconds (e.g. Car A is 4103 ms ahead of Car B).

**Variable 2** - The duration of the process from start to finish (e.g. 60 seconds)

Result:

The result is a % of the ideal speed that varies over the duration of the process.

### Formula 1

Given the known distance between Car A and B in milliseconds and the duration of the process in seconds, the formula of the curve that provides the speed of Car B changing over time (in % of ideal speed) that will result in Car B catching up to Car A, so that they end up traveling at the same speed (100% of ideal speed) and next to each other.

[Acceleration Curve Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSbPd.png)

### Formula 2

Given the known distance between Car A and B in milliseconds and the duration of the process in seconds, the formula of the curve that provides the speed of Car A changing over time (in % of ideal speed) that will result in Car A slowing down to match Car B, so that they end up traveling at the same speed (100% of ideal speed) and next to each other.

[Deceleration Curve Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l51Vj.png)

Hope someone out there is able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your speed curve looks like $$v(t)=v_0+c\cdot(1-\cos \omega t),\qquad 0\le t\le T. $$
In order to have exactly one "bulge", we need $\omega T=2\pi$, so $\omega=\frac{2\pi}T$.
The positional difference compared to a car at constant speed $v_0$ will finally be
$$\int_0^Tc(1-\cos\omega t)\,\mathrm dt =cT$$
because the cosine averages out. Thus we want $c=\frac{\Delta s}T$.
Instead of a spacial distance $\Delta s$, you specified a temporal distance $\Delta t$. But of course $\Delta s=v_0\Delta t$, so we end up with $c=\frac{v_0\Delta T}T$,
$$v(t)=v_0\cdot\left(1\pm\frac{\Delta T}T\left(1-\cos\frac{2\pi t}{T}\right) \right).$$

Comment: Thank you @Hagen von Eitzen - I'll attempt to implement this so that I can test that this suits.